# Designing a hand history class for Texas Hold'em in Java

Tags: java, poker

I am trying to come up with a Java hand history class for Texas Hold'em and wanted to bounce an idea off here.

Requirements are that every action is stored and there is an efficient way to traverse each HandHistory object (which would represent a single played hand) to match common 'lines' like the standard continuation bet (i.e. the preflop raiser who was in late position preflop and probably is in position postflop is checked to and then makes a 75%ish pot bet).

Ignore for the moment that the definitions for each of the lines is fuzzy at best. As a first stab, I was thinking of organizing it like so:

```
public class HandHistory {
    private Integer handnumber;
    //in case we saw things at showdown, put them here
    private HashMap<Player,String> playerHands; 
    private String flopCards;
    private String turnCard;
    private String riverCard;
    private HashMap<BetRound,LinkedHashMap<Integer,ArrayList<PlayerAction>>> actions;
}
```

So, for each betround we store a linked hashmap whose keys are integers that are the offsets from first position to act for that betround, so preflop UTG is 0.

We generate the actions in position order already, so use a linked hashmap so we can iterate nicely later and skip over positions that are sitting out,etc.

Each arraylist will contain the actions that that position had in that betround. Most of the time this array will have one element, but in cases like, limps and then calls, it will have two.

Can anyone see a better data structure to use for this?

Answer (score 1):

small change, since holdem has a fixed number of betting rounds, maybe

```
private HashMap<BetRound,LinkedHashMap<Integer,ArrayList<PlayerAction>>> actions;
```

could just be:

```
private LinkedHashMap<Integer,ArrayList<PlayerAction>>[] actions= new ... ;
```

also, here's a couple of books that may be of interest:

[http://www.amazon.com/Poker-strategy-Winning-game-theory/dp/0399506691](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0399506691)

[http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Poker-Bill-Chen/dp/1886070253](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1886070253)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Card {
  // ??? probably just an int (0 to 51), but certainly not a String. 
  // Instead of using class Card below, directly using an int woulb be OK.
}

class Hand {
  Set<Card> hand; // size 2
}

class Draw { // not sure of the exact poker name for the 5 cards
  Set<Card> flop;  // size 3
  Card turn;
  Card river;
}

class Bet {
  Player player;
  // or maybe "Double" instead; then amount == null means player dropping out.
  // or use 0.0 to mean dropped out.
  double amount;
}

class BettingRound {
  // Includes initial "entry" and all subsequent calls.
  // Should include players dropping out also.
  List<Bet> bets;
}

class Game {
  Draw draw;
  Map<Player, Hand> hands;
  // rounds 0 and 1 are special since turn and river are not shown
  List<BettingRound> rounds;
}
```

You should also know how much money each player has, I guess. You could keep track of that with a third field (total cash before the bet) in class Bet.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it for a bit more, I think I have answered my own question. I've decided not to try to both store every action in a tabular way and try to get quick lookup of frequency counts for betting lines in the same data structure.

Instead, I am going to use my class above as the database-like storage to disk and use a DAG for the betting lines where the edges are tuples of {action, position, players ahead} and the vertices are frequency counts. I think a DAG is correct over a trie here since I do want multiple edges coming into a vertex since lines with common suffix are considered close.